# Connect to SQL Server query from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

i am trying to connect to a query that is build in sql server, but i cannot find where is it saved (the address). Just to clarify - no trouble connecting to tables on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to a query in SQL Server from Excel.
You can connect and retrieve data from tables and views.